# PHP JSON Encode multidimensional SQL Response

Tags: php, json

I have three Tables:
Persons
and
Interest
and
Persons_Interests

There are like 20 Interests and hundrets of Persons.
Every Person could have 0, 1 or multiple Interests.

I dont know how to get all Persons with every Interests per Person and encode it to json with PHP.

I also want to get the Result with prepared Statements from my sql database by PersonID.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

My Problem is that the json_encode does not print the interests per person.

Thank you

Comment: Could you add your code, the actual output and the desired output please ?

Comment: The problem is that i get multiple rows from the sql result. But I want one row per Person in the json result. and every person should contain an additional array or object which holds the interests

Comment: Ok, but nobody here will write this code without see what you tried first and where exactly your are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL looks something like this:

```
select p.name, i.name from persons as p
outer join persons_interests as pi on p.id = pi.person_id
left join interests as i on pi.interest_id = i.id
```

and `$personsInterests` is the result of that query, you should be able to use a `foreach` loop to build your `$result` array

```
$result = [];
foreach ($personsInterests as $interest) {
    if (isset($result[$interest[0]])) {
        $result[$interest[0]][] = $interest[1]; 
    } else {
        $result[$interest[0]] = isset($interest[1]) ? [$interest[1]] : [];
    }
}
```

and then `json_encode($result)`

Answer (score -1):

Order your sql by PersonID. After you've fetched the rows, lets think you got rows like that:

PersonID | InterestID

- 1|1
- 1| 2
- 1| 4
- 2| 3
- 2|1
- 2|2
- 3|5

For this really easy example you would Walk over your array and rearrange the Data in a new Array

```
sortedArray= [];
Foreach(result as row) {
    If(empty(sortedArray[row['PersonID']])) {
        sortedArray[row['PersonID']]['Interests'][] = row['InterestID'];
    }
}
```

Thats onl an easy example. it depends on how you want the final Array Looks like.